# jQuery event cleared after setting value of observerable

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an initialisation function applies Knockout bindings and binds some other events using jQuery delegate.

```
init = function (){

    ko.applyBindings(_data);

    $('#tabs').tabs();

    $('#container').delegate(".expand_all", "click", (function () {...})
}
```

The view model has an observable and a function that changes the observable after an ajax call:

```
function(data){

    var self = this;
    var name = ko.observable(data.name);

    self.changeName = function(){
        getName(function(data){
            ......
            self.name(data.name);
            ......
            ......
        }
    }
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<div id="container">
    <a href='#' data-bind='click: changeName'></a>
    <div id="tabs">
          <ul>
                 <li>......</li>
                 <li>......</li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <a href='#' class="expand_all"></a>
</div>
```

Strangely, after changeName is triggered, the event bindings on #tabs, and #div have been lost.

Anyone please shed some light?

Comment: offtopic: why you need change name using another method? you could directly use `name("NEW_NAME")`! Couldn't you?

Comment: Sorry @HungryCoder, the changeName function does some other stuff as well, I will update the code to reflect that.

Comment: @Prinzhorn, how to show markup?

Comment: @Will Markup = HTML. Just paste it here (the important parts) like your code. Both Knockout and jQuery interact with it.

Comment: Is that view model function above actually being called as a constructor?

Answer (score 2):

knockout.js observables should be public, not private:

```
self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
```

As written, there is no `self.name()` function available as called in your `self.changeName()` callback, because the `name` variable was incorrectly declared private.

It's very likely that you'll find an exception in your browser's console.

Comment: As pointed out by Alnitak, my [deleted] answer is misguiding and this is the solution to the bug in Wills code.

Comment: @JanSommer you deserve some credit for spotting the private/public mismatch in the first place.  I couldn't see it when I was reading the question.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for your answers, however, it wasn't the problem. The observerable name updates perfectly without any error in the browser console. The problem is the update of the observerable somehow clears the .tabs() and .delegate() which was called in the init().

Comment: so are you replacing the contents of those elements in the AJAX call?

Comment: nope, the callback function of the ajax call only change the value of the observerable 'name' and trigger a couple alert boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Will a custom binding solve your problem?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, 
                   allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var $elem = $(element);
        // Apply event handler on $elem

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, 
                     allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        // Handle value updated here

    }
};
```

In your markup:

```
<a href='#' data-bind='myBindingName: changeName'></a>
```

Comment: @ Anders Nygaard can you please explain a little bit more? How a custom binding could solve my problem? thanks!

Comment: It gives you a more explisit control of the DOM elements you are binding. In stead of calling ko.applyBindings(viewModel) and then doing some jQuery on all elements with a given classname or id, this approach will let you apply the jQuery you need to each element as they are bound to the view model.

Comment: Also, the binding has an update event, so you can manipulate the element, add/remove bindings etc when the value has mutated on your view model.